# Al intentar pintar un dato recibo undefined en angular

Tags: json, angular

Estoy intentando pintar el resultado de un json y siempre recibo undefined.

este es el json que recibo :

```
{antecedentes: Array(1), ultimaconsulta: Array(1), paciente: Array(1)}
antecedentes: Array(1)
0: {idHc: "1", identificacion: "0960205367", creadohc: "2021-06-10 17:01:25", alcohol: "sdfdsf", tabaco: "sdfsdf", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
paciente: Array(1)
0: {idPaciente: "101", nombre: "JUan de los Palotes", email: "xxx@cc.com", password: "sdsdweweewf", creadopaciente: "2008-06-07 18:19:43", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
ultimaconsulta: Array(1)
0: {idConsultas: "1", fechaConsulta: "2021-05-10 18:16:08", descripcion: "dsdcfas", identificacion: "0960205367", reConsulta: "2021-08-14 18:14:46", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

mediante esta consulta en el service

```
getHistoriaPorCedula(termino: string): Observable<General> {
    return this.httpClient.get<General>(
      `${this.baseUrl}/pacientes/gethistoria/${termino}`
    );
  }
```

en el component.ts tengo este codigo

```
export class HistoriaClinicaComponent implements OnInit {
  pacientes!: Pacientes;
  isLoading: Boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private pacientesService: PacientesService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(({ id }) => {
      this.pacientesService.getHistoriaPorCedula(id).subscribe((general) => {
        this.pacientes = general.paciente;
        this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
        console.log(general);
        console.log(this.pacientes);
        console.log(this.pacientes.nombre)
      });

    });
  }
}
```

y en console log de los pacientes recibo esto

```
[{…}]0: birthday: "1972-05-01"creadopaciente: "2008-06-07 18:19:43"direccion: "casa de la yuca"email: "xxx@cc.com"escolaridad: "inicial"estado: "V"idPaciente: "101"identificacion: "0960205367"nombre: "JUan de los Palotes"ocupacion: "taxista"password: "sdsdweweewf"sexo: "M"telefono: "+000000000000"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
historia-clinica.component.ts:28 

undefined
```

el valor undefined corresponde al console.log(this.pacientes.nombre)

cualquier ayuda es bien recibida..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de mucho buscar y probar encontre una solución.

Cambie el componente a asi

```
export class HistoriaClinicaComponent implements OnInit {
  general!: General;
  pacientes!: Paciente;
  antecedentes!: Antecedente;
  ultimaconsulta!: Ultimaconsulta;
  isLoading: Boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private pacientesService: PacientesService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(({ id }) => {
      this.pacientesService.getHistoriaPorCedula(id).subscribe(
        (general) => {
          this.utilizarDatos(general);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(<any>error);
        }
      );
    });
  }

     
  private utilizarDatos(general: General) {
    this.general = general;
    let { antecedentes, paciente, ultimaconsulta } = this.general;

    paciente.forEach((paciente) => (this.pacientes = paciente));
    antecedentes.forEach((antecedentes) => (this.antecedentes = antecedentes));
    ultimaconsulta.forEach((ultimaconsulta) => (this.ultimaconsulta = ultimaconsulta));

    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;

  }
}
```

la interface quedo asi

```
export interface General {
  antecedentes:   Antecedente[];
  ultimaconsulta: Ultimaconsulta[];
  paciente:       Paciente[];
}

export interface Antecedente {
  idHc:               string;
  identificacion:     string;
  creadohc:           Date;
  alcohol:            string;
  tabaco:             string;
  drogas:             string;
  infusiones:         null;
  alimentacion:       null;
  diuresis:           null;
  sueno:              null;
  infancia:           null;
  respiratorias:      null;
  gastrointestinales: null;
  nefrourologicos:    null;
  neurologicos:       null;
  hematologicos:      null;
  quirurgico:         null;
  alergicos:          null;
  traumatologico:     null;
}

export interface Paciente {
  idPaciente:     string;
  nombre:         string;
  email:          string;
  password:       string;
  creadopaciente: Date;
  identificacion: string;
  ocupacion:      string;
  sexo:           string;
  estado:         string;
  escolaridad:    string;
  birthday:       Date;
  direccion:      string;
  telefono:       string;
}

export interface Ultimaconsulta {
  idConsultas:    string;
  fechaConsulta:  Date;
  descripcion:    string;
  identificacion: string;
  reConsulta:     Date;
  medicamentos:   string;
  metodo:         string;
}
```

el json recibido

```
{
  "antecedentes": [
    {
      "idHc": "1",
      "identificacion": "0960205367",
      "creadohc": "2021-06-10 17:01:25",
      "alcohol": "sdfdsf",
      "tabaco": "sdfsdf",
      "drogas": "sdfsdfsdfsdfsd",
      "infusiones": null,
      "alimentacion": null,
      "diuresis": null,
      "sueno": null,
      "infancia": null,
      "respiratorias": null,
      "gastrointestinales": null,
      "nefrourologicos": null,
      "neurologicos": null,
      "hematologicos": null,
      "quirurgico": null,
      "alergicos": null,
      "traumatologico": null
    }
  ],
  "ultimaconsulta": [
    {
      "idConsultas": "1",
      "fechaConsulta": "2021-05-10 18:16:08",
      "descripcion": "dsdcfas",
      "identificacion": "0960205367",
      "reConsulta": "2021-08-14 18:14:46",
      "medicamentos": "ontrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.",
      "metodo": "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. "
    }
  ],
  "paciente": [
    {
      "idPaciente": "101",
      "nombre": "JUan de los Palotes",
      "email": "xxx@cc.com",
      "password": "sdsdweweewf",
      "creadopaciente": "2008-06-07 18:19:43",
      "identificacion": "0960205367",
      "ocupacion": "taxista",
      "sexo": "M",
      "estado": "V",
      "escolaridad": "inicial",
      "birthday": "1972-05-01",
      "direccion": "casa de la yuca",
      "telefono": "+000000000000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Todo fue resuelto con el uso de `.forEach`  espero que le pueda servir la solución a alguien más.

happy codding!! a todos